# Highcarts bar legend symbol alignment to the label

Tags: highcharts

If I modify the symbol Width/Height in a bar-chart the symbol is "bottom" aligned with the legend text. Is there a way to "middle - align" them?

http://jsfiddle.net/klodoma/h8j0kL1e/

```
 legend: {
    ...
    symbolHeight: 5,
    symbolWidth: 5,
    symbolRadius: 0,
    ...
  },
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate and set `translateY` attribute for legend symbol SVG elements:

```
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var legendItems = this.legend.allItems,
                textBbox,
                symbolBbox;

            legendItems.forEach(function(item) {
                textBbox = item.legendItem.getBBox();
                symbolBbox = item.legendSymbol.getBBox();

                item.legendSymbol.attr({
                    translateY: symbolBbox.height - textBbox.height / 2
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a0ye5tuw/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr

Comment: I've posted a fix, which is more accurate 
y: textBbox.y + (textBbox.height - symbolBbox.height) / 2

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to use CSS *"it's dirty but it works"*

```
.highcharts-point{
  transform: translate(0, -10px)
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/yjvm6xbs/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/klodoma/p5mdy19u/

Based on the answer from @ppotaczek I've aligned the Y so that it's always middle aligned, no matter what the symbol size is.

```
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var legendItems = this.legend.allItems,
                textBbox,
                symbolBbox;

            legendItems.forEach(function(item) {
                textBbox = item.legendItem.getBBox();
                symbolBbox = item.legendSymbol.getBBox();

                item.legendSymbol.attr({
                    y: textBbox.y + (textBbox.height - symbolBbox.height) / 2
                });
            });
        }
    }
```